# How can I restore mobility to player in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in the middle of a dialogue when i was arrested in skyrim and now I have no control of my character. I can still move the camera a bit and open the menus but I can't walk or quick travel. Also using the console command "enableplayercontrols" has no effect and does not do anything.

Comment: @Wouter said it is asked before, just reload a older safe file. its a bug